# Where do I find the HTML Markup on One Page Checkout: echo $_rate->getMethodDescription()

Tags: checkout, shipping, onestepcheckout

At OnePageCheckout in magento under `app/design/frontend/themename/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/availible.phtml`I found this entry

```
<?php echo $_rate->getMethodDescription(); ?>
```

It's the ul/li list with shipping costs

```
<ul class="shippingList">
  <li>One : 2,94&nbsp;€</li>
  <li>Two : 0,00&nbsp;€</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

How can I change that list to an table .. WHERE do  I find the HTML?
Thanks for your help. And by the way .. How can I find it in future, if I have only the Method in my phtml-file ..

Answer (score 2):

What I do to find out where the code can be found:
If you have access to your server via SSH, you can grep for it:

```
grep -r "getMethodDescription" * 2>/dev/null
```

Result is (file and containing text):

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php: * @method string getMethodDescription()
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php:                ->setMethodDescription($rate->getMethodDescription())
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml:                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle() ? $_rate->getMethodTitle() : $_rate->getMethodDescription()) ?> -
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml:            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle() ? $_rate->getMethodTitle() : $_rate->getMethodDescription()) ?> -
```

So you see, there are 4 Results.

If I grep for the template (shipping/method/form.phtml) I can find out, what the block type is and in which layout xml file it's defined:

```
grep -r "shipping/method/form.phtml" * 2>/dev/null
```

Result:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml:   <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method_form" template="sales/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml" name="form" />
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml:   <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method_form" template="sales/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml" name="form" />
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml:   <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method_form" template="sales/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml" name="form" />
```

So Block Type is adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method_form.